Error when train model with 2 output classes in Image Classification Mushroom
I have a complaint during the model train that may be caused by my code syntax. I want to create a mushroom image classification model that will produce 2 outputs to appear on mobile apps (tflite deploy to mobile apps). I created 2 classes for the output where there are types of mushrooms, namely Edible and Non-Edible Mushroom and also the name of the mushroom type which has 20 names of mushroom type names. In the code below, I used mobilnetV2 transfer learning :
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

# Load the MobileNetV2 model with pre-trained weights
IMG_SHAPE = (224, 224, 3)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=IMG_SHAPE)

# Freeze the base model
base_model.trainable = False

# Add custom layers on top of the base model
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

# Output layer for classifying mushroom type (20 classes)
mushroom_class = Dense(20, activation='softmax', name='mushroom_class')(x)

# Output layer for classifying edibility (2 classes)
edibility_output = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='edibility_output')(x)
# edibility_output = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='edibility_output')(x)

# Create the full model with two outputs
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=[edibility_output, mushroom_class])

# Summary of the model
model.summary()

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import sparse_categorical_crossentropy
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(),
              loss={'edibility_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 'mushroom_class': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'mushroom_class': 'accuracy', 'edibility_output': 'accuracy'})

I also created a custom generator to classify the types of mushrooms and the names of the types of mushrooms.
def custom_generator(generator):
    while True:
        x, y = generator.next()
        # Split labels into two parts: 1-class edible and 20-class mushroom types
        edible_labels = y[:, :2]  # Assuming the first column is edible labels
        mushroom_labels = y[:, 0:20]  # The remaining columns are mushroom type labels
        yield x, {'edibility_output': edible_labels, 'mushroom_class': mushroom_labels}

train_generator_custom = custom_generator(train_generator)
validation_generator_custom = custom_generator(validation_generator)

For the folder directory place, more or less like the image below:


I also declared ImageDataGenerator :
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Path to your training and validation directories
train_dir = 'mushroom3/MO_95/mushroom_dataset/train'
validation_dir = 'mushroom3/MO_95/mushroom_dataset/test'

train_ediblemushroom_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'Edible')
train_inediblemushroom_dir = os.path.join(train_dir, 'Non-Edible')

validation_ediblemushroom_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'Edible')
validation_inediblemushroom_dir = os.path.join(validation_dir, 'Non-Edible')

# Define ImageDataGenerator for training data
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

# validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Generate batches of augmented data from the directories
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=20,
    class_mode='categorical'  # Because you have multiple classes
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=20,
    class_mode='categorical'  # Because you have multiple classes
)

This is the code syntax for train model :
history = model.fit(
    train_generator_custom,
    steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
    epochs=200,
    validation_data=validation_generator_custom,
    validation_steps=len(validation_generator)
)

When I want to train the model, the following error message appears :
InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:
........
........
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[20,20] labels_size=[20,2]
     [[{{node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_8124]

Can anyone help with the error message in my script code?
I want the mobile apps to produce output for mushroom types and names of mushroom types with tflite after I create tflite.


the model definition is correct (however I would consider using dict in model outputs attribute). My guess is the shape of the inputs is where the problem lays. Check this mock example that is based on your code, but uses random data and correct shape of your inputs to be aligned with this example:
def custom_generator(n_samples = 20):
    """ Iterator that returns random data. 
    
        Arguments:
          n_samples - same as `batch_size`
    """

    while True:
        x = tf.random.normal([n_samples, 224, 244,3])

        n_classes = 2
        # shape of [n_samples, 1]
        indices = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([[0.5] * n_classes]), n_samples)[0]
        # shape of [n_samples, 2]
        edible_labels = tf.one_hot(indices, depth = n_classes)

        n_classes = 20
        # shape of [n_samples, 1]
        indices = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([[0.5] * n_classes]), n_samples)[0]
        # shape of [n_samples, 20]
        mushroom_onehot = tf.one_hot(indices, depth = n_classes)


        yield x, {'edibility_output': edible_labels, 'mushroom_class': mushroom_onehot}



n_steps = 60
train_generator_custom = custom_generator()
validation_generator_custom = custom_generator()

# Create the full model with two outputs
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, 
              outputs={'edibility_output':edibility_output, 
                       'mushroom_class':mushroom_class})


# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(),
              loss={'edibility_output': 'binary_crossentropy', 
                    'mushroom_class': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              metrics={'mushroom_class': 'accuracy', 'edibility_output': 'accuracy'})


history = model.fit(
    train_generator_custom,
    steps_per_epoch=n_steps,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=validation_generator_custom,
    validation_steps=n_steps
)



Thank you for the answer, For now, my model can output the Edible class, but when classifying non-edible class images. An error appears:  Error list index out. If the IndexError: list index out of range error problem, is it related to the non-edible mushroom class or the lack of non-edible class as in the attached screenshot link?

Hello Rafif, Sry, but I don't see anywhere in the question references to edible_class_name. Is this a new code that you not yet published?
